# Can't understand the mysql self left-join query

Tags: mysql, left-join, self-join, anti-join

I come across a query which is,

```
SELECT it1.survey_set_id, it1.type, it1.value FROM survey_condition_filter it1 LEFT JOIN survey_condition_filter it2 ON(it1.survey_set_id = it2.survey_set_id AND it2.type = 3002) WHERE it1.type IN (2000, 2001, 2002) AND it2.value IS NULL;
```

Why is  self left-join is used in the above query.

```
SELECT survey_set_id, type, value FROM survey_condition_filter WHERE type IN (2000, 2001, 2002);
```

isn't the above query is equivalent to the first query which used self left-join. since the query is just also filtering the `IN (2000, 2001, 2002) AND it2.value IS NULL`. I am confused the use of join query here and can't really understand the working of the first query.

This is table **survey_condition_filter**

```
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| survey_id     | bigint       | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| survey_set_id | bigint       | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| type          | int          | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| condition     | tinyint      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| value         | varchar(15)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| display_value | text         | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| order         | int          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| created_at    | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| created_by    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| updated_at    | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| updated_by    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| deleted_at    | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| deleted_by    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an anti join. We outer join a table, but then only keep the outer joined rows (by applying `WHERE ... it2.value IS NULL` here). It is much more common - and much more readable in my opinion - to use a straight-forward `NOT EXISTS` (or `NOT IN` in many situations).

```
SELECT it1.survey_set_id, it1.type, it1.value
FROM survey_condition_filter it1 
WHERE it1.type IN (2000, 2001, 2002) 
AND NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT null
  FROM survey_condition_filter it2 
  WHERE it2.survey_set_id = it1.survey_set_id
  AND it2.type = 3002
);
```

What this query does is obvious: select all type 2000/2001/2002 rows where not exists a 3002 row for the same survey_set_id .

If survey_set_id is a non-nullable column, you can use `NOT IN`, which gets the query even a tad shorter:

```
SELECT it1.survey_set_id, it1.type, it1.value
FROM survey_condition_filter it1 
WHERE it1.type IN (2000, 2001, 2002) 
AND itl.survey_set_id NOT IN
(
  SELECT it2.survey_set_id
  FROM survey_condition_filter it2 
  WHERE it2.type = 3002
);
```